# Adobe DTM to set query string in eVar and sProp

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

So normally I would use the s.getQueryParam(); to parse out my URLs for query strings that I've been using.

s.eVar8=s.getQueryParam('cid,pid,eid',':');
s.prop28=s.getQueryParam('Role');

But since DTM has that all built into it, how would you really define that? I know I can set a page load rule using the campaign variable, but what if I have multiple parameters separated by ":"

www.domain.com?cid=blah1:blah2:blah3&pid=blah4:blah5:blah6&eid=blah7:blah8:blah9

Is there something that I'm missing when using this approach? Should I be capture these values into a data element then passing the data element into a page load rule using an eVar or sProp?

Comment: The ideal approach is to create a data element that replicates functionality of `getQueryParam`, yes

Comment: Okay - but passing multiple values like query strings into a single eVar....what about passing multiple values into a single eVar/prop - how would you capture this? Am I just really over thinking this whole process?

Comment: You can use the URL Param data element type for a single param, but DTM doesn't have have an full equivalent to `getQueryParam` functionality. So you need to replicate it using your own js code with a Custom Type data element.

Comment: @Brando: Remember, you can pass a delimited string using either a list prop or a list var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For variables that only look for a single URL parameter:**

Create a **Data Element** of **Type** `URL Parameter`.  For **Parameter Name**, put e.g. "Role" (no quotes) for `prop28`. Alternatively, you can do the same thing below, for multiple.

**For variables that look for multiple URL parameters:**

Create a **Data Element** of **Type** `Custom Script`.  Click the `[Open Editor]` button and in the code box, add the following:

```
var d=':',
    p=['cid','pid','eid'],
    v=[],c,l,q;
for (c=0,l=p.length;c<l;c++) {
  q=_satellite.getQueryParamCaseInsensitive(p[c]);
  if (q) v.push(q);
}
return v.join(d);
```

The `d=` and `p=` values are based on what you have for `eVar8`. This isn't 100% the same as AA's `s.getQueryParam` plugin but it's most of it; the parts you care about based on your posted code.

**Reference the Data Element(s)**

In the **Adobe Analytics** tool config, in the **Global Variables** section, you can add your prop(s) and eVar(s) there, using `%data_element_name_here%` syntax.

Comment: AH! That makes total sense. Thanks, CV!

Comment: Here's an interesting one. I just tested it and's erroring out.

www.domain.com?cid=test1 -- breaks
www.domain.com?pid=test1 -- works
www.domain.com?eid=test1 -- works
www.domain.com?cid=test1&pid=test1&eid=test1 -- breaks
www.domain.com?pid=test1&eid=test1 -- works

It's only breaking when I add "cid" to the mix.

Comment: @Brando the code works fine on my sandbox. I'm not sure where you went wrong but you will have to be more specific than just saying it's "erroring out" and "breaking".

Comment: Sorry @Crayon Violent - I started editing my comment last week and got side tracked. But I found the problem - turns out the "cid" value is interfering with internal search, causing _satellite from getting defined. Regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: As per the below link the _satellite.getQueryParam() and _satellite.getQueryParamCaseInsensitive() are not safe to use. https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/object_reference.html Do you have any other option to get query param in DataElement?.

Comment: @EldhoVarghese while you are technically correct, and officially I will agree and "use-at-your-own-risk" disclaimer it... in practice I think it's okay. Adobe has stated they have no plans on doing any major changes or updates to DTM, in favor of progressing Launch. So, in practice, that function will almost certainly never be touched. But yeah, OP is welcome to roll their own function if they want to be super safe about it.